# Multiple View Controllers in a single VIPER module

Tags: ios, swift, architecture, viper-architecture

I'm building my first app using VIPER architecture. I have two VCs: the main one and the modal one (presented modally from the main VC). There is a tableView inside my modal VC, and when the user selects a row there, I need to pass it to presenter and then from presenter to the main VC. I also need to keep the selected row highlighted in the modal VC, so if I close it and then present it again, the row will be still highlighted. I'm confused, because I don't know what's the best way to do it. What I've tried is including my modal VC into configurator and calling configurator two times: in the main VC and then again in the modal VC. It works fine. That's what my configurator looks like:

```
protocol ObserverConfiguratorProtocol {
    func configure(with mainViewController: ObserverViewController, with modalViewController: CurrenciesViewController)
}

class ObserverConfigurator: ObserverConfiguratorProtocol {
    
    func configure(with mainViewController: ObserverViewController, with modalViewController: CurrenciesViewController) {
        
        let presenter = ObserverPresenter(view: mainViewController)
        let interactor = ObserverInteractor(presenter: presenter)
        let router = ObserverRouter(view: mainViewController)
        
        mainViewController.presenter = presenter
        modalViewController.presenter = presenter
        
        presenter.interactor = interactor
        presenter.router = router
        presenter.view = mainViewController
        presenter.modalView = modalViewController
    }
    
}
```

viewDidLoad() in the main VC:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        configurator.configure(with: self, view: CurrenciesViewController())
    }
```

viewDidLoad() in the modal VC:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        configurator.configure(with: ObserverViewController(), view: self)
    }
```

Anyway, I'm not sure it corresponds VIPER principles. Does it, or there are better solutions? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to present another view controller, it should be on its own module for VIPER. `ObserverViewController` should not know about the presence of `CurrenciesViewController`.

Instead, only `ObserverRouter` should know about how to build `CurrenciesModule` and present and pass data into it. Something like this:

```
final class CurrenciesBuilder {
    @available(*, unavailable) private init() { }

    static func build(routerDelegate: ObserverRouterDelegate, selectedIndex: IndexPath?) -> CurrenciesViewProtocol {
        let service = CurrenciesService()
        let interactor = CurrenciesInteractor(service: service, selectedIndex: selectedIndex)

        let view = CurrenciesViewController(nibName: String(describing: CurrenciesViewController.self), bundle: nil)
        let router = CurrenciesRouter(vc: view)
        router.delegate = routerDelegate

        let presenter = CurrenciesPresenter(interactor: interactor,
                                            view: view,
                                            router: router)
        view.presenter = presenter

        return view
    }
}
```

So, whenever you need to present `CurrenciesViewController`, you could pass `selectedIndex` and it can highlight it, if applicable. I would pass the information to the interactor, and let presenter know about it and do some changes in the view.

For passing the `selectedIndex` back to `ObserverViewController`, you could create a `ObserverRouterDelegate` that can be triggered when `CurrenciesViewController` is going to be dismissed.

```
protocol ObserverRouterDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didDismiss(with selectedIndex: IndexPath?)
}
```

To wrap up; there should be 2 modules, `ObserverModule` and `CurrenciesModule`, that should have bidirectional connection through their routers. Since routers are responsible for presenting/dismissing views (and they hold a connection to their views), they can update their views and/or let the peer router update their own views.

Comment: Thank you for making it clear! I created two modules, as you said, and it works as expected.